# Ubuntu тормозит

Tags: производительность, ubuntu

Установил убунту (11.04) на нетбук, сначала просто летел, прошло пару месяцев, теперь жутко тормозит и с каждым днем все хуже, что можно сделать? В винде был дефрагмент, антивирусы, всякие clean registry и много утилит и способов повышения производительностьи, может и здесь что-то подобное ест? Кто-нибудь знает? Может отключить какие-то ненужные сервисы надо?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: может просто нетбук запылился и греется?

Comment: Да нет, дружище, я тоже так думал, открыл, там пыли-то почти не было, и не очень он нагревается, я его всего то 7 месяцев использую, а брал я его новеньким.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй почистить систему http://ubuntovod.ru/soft/optimizaciya-ubuntu.htmlа еще если машина слабая, попробуй вместо гномов, кедов или что там у тебя тайлинговые менеджеры, awesome очень хорош!

Comment: попробовал чистку по вашей ссылке,вроде почисил, но разницы никакой,а гном не сменял,так как ранще он же и летал,спасибо за ответ,но мне бы причину выясьнить ховется а не менять что то

Answer (score 1):

Netbook Acer AspireOne - Intel Atom 1.60, 2Gb, 160Gb.40 Gb - Xp Home (шла в поставке) + 60 Gb (NTFS) + Ubuntu 10.04.2 (20 Ext4 (/) + 36 Ext4 (/home + раздел подкачки ). Сначала устанавливается Xp, потом Ubuntu 10.04.2 ( с ручной разметкой разделов). Не забудьте "отрезать" раздел NTFS  без форматирования и примонтировать как windows. Полтора года без "тормозов".

Comment: Дружок я решить проблему хочу а не отвертется от нее

Answer (score 1):

для начала понаблюдать за TOP или, лучше htop для начала, там будет понятней. почистить /tmp и пользовательские темпа. Потестить оперативу на всяк случай, у меня на чутка битой оперативе на Mandriva все начало тоже баловаться, пока не понял в чём дело. Ротация логов включена? может еще в какой-то папке очень много файлов, можно скрипт написать, что бы прошелся по винту, посчитал в какой папке сколько файлов - просто количество для каждой папки. SMART на винте проверить. Из этого либо что-то станет понятнее, либо искать еще варианты))) А вообще логи в этих делах посмотреть повнимательнее, тоже бывает полезно

> правда 11.04 тормознее 10.04.согласен. Ставил 11 убунту и минт, откатился на 10-ку

Answer (score 1):

При загрузке, убунта скорее всего грузится в графическом режиме, нажми esc, появится консольный режим, посмотри какие сервисы загружаются, что возможно но не обязательно:

1. убунта будет проверять и исправлять ошибки разделов том числе и раздела винды, исправляется путем стятия системной задачи "проверять диски", в настройках загрузки
2. может искать сеть, запускать разные файрволы, проверять и скачивать обновление, тоже самое в настройках загрузки поотключай эти сервисы
3. найди утилиту qps(если нет sudo apt-get и.т.д.) или похожую, посмотри какие процессы занимают оперативную память и убей их, лишее в последующем отключи или удали(sudo, dpkg -e  название пакета
4. в любом случае отключи автоматический поиск и установку обновлений

Answer (score 0):

Установить Ubuntu Twiak- оно есть в репозиториях, а он чистит систему лучше , удаляет старые ядра. В общем дружу с пингвинами уже более года всё летает, правда 11.04 тормознее 10.04.